# Display facebook buiness page's reviews on my own website

Tags: php, facebook

I thought this would be relatively simple.

My client has a business Facebook page with a dozen good reviews. He wants these on his site.

All I need is a JSON or XML stream of these reviews I can the process with PHP and display.

I have setup a App with ID and secret key.

```
<?
session_start();
include_once('facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('VALID_ID', 'VALID_SECRET');

// If you're making app-level requests:
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

// To validate the session:

if($session->validate()){
    echo 'okay';
}

$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/670868943020497/ratings'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */

?>
```

The session validates and echos "okay" but then throws a fatal error whenever I try and use it to access any graph data.

Any help greatfully appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From the Facebook docs:

> A page access token is required to retrieve this data.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/ratings

It seems that you are only using an App Access Token. You need to authorize a user with `manage_pages` to get a Page Token. If you don't know how to deal with Access Tokens, take a look at those links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/